# Concat row/column headers for all positive fields in sparse matrix?

Tags: sorting, if-statement, google-sheets-formula, flatten, textjoin

For a website internationalization project, I have a Google Sheets with countries and languages that we would like to offer within that country.

Shortened sample sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JNftjuEy97KeHfEH80bwl6H-40nNohPQrnQ-W_lzDZA/
The actual matrix is much bigger.

|  | en | de | fr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| US | 1 |  |  |
| DE | 1 | 2 |  |
| FR | 2 |  | 1 |

The numbers determine the order in which the languages should be offered in the country's language menu.

Now, I would like to use a formula to extract a list of required locales.

Such as: US-en,DE-en,DE-de,FR-fr,FR-en

The table keeps on changing, so a formula would be preferred to a one-time solution.

Comment: I realize that the syntax for the locales is uncommon for anyone using linux/unix. Yet, it is the strange way that we would like to express locales within that project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, IF(B2:D4>0, A2:A4&"-"&B1:D1, )))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(TEXTJOIN(",", 1, INDEX(IFERROR(SORT(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(B2:D4>0, A2:A4&"-"&B1:D1&"​"&B2:D4&"​"&ROW(B2:D4), )), "​"), 3, 1, 2, 1)),,1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is already really helpful. It just gets the order wrong. It should be `…,FR-fr,FR-en` in the end.

Comment: Thank you a lot! The update gets the order right and I accepted it as the answer. In the end, I even understood how the formular works, allthough I would not have been able to produce it myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise you can use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(",",1,MID(SORT(FLATTEN(IF(B2:D4<>"",ROW(A2:A4)*1000+B2:D4&A2:A4&"-"&B1:D1,""))),5,100)))
```

create a sort order by value in the range, then join them.

Comment: Thank you Terio! player0 was slightly faster, but I also get the idea of this formula!